# Multi layered image textures problem in Blender Cycles

Tags: texturing, image

I'm a total newbie at Blender... I've been trying to simulate foil effects on a mylar balloon design. All fine until I add holographic foil effects via video textures. I can't make the black elements of the design (a drop shadow on the text) visible. Blender just renders it as alpha. Any ideas? Have I just got too many textures working at once?[image]

[image]

Comment: It would be easier to understand your node tree if you annotate what element is doing what. My feeling, not understanding what you are after, is that you are using add nodes when you need mix nodes... but I would need more info.

Comment: Hi, yeah there are several redundant commands on there where I was basically trying to plug anything into anything! Here's an annotated version of the node tree...http://tinyurl.com/q4acr73  And this is how the balloon should look... http://tinyurl.com/og2ztwx

Comment: As I'd say after looking on your reference image, you'd like to make those black cracks on your result influence on the displacement of the mesh. There are at least 2 often used ways: 1. Plug image with black cracks as a bump map (and preferably create a normal map from image) 2. Using sculpting, model those relief parts by hand (the mesh should be highpoly for that).

Comment: Thanks, I tried the bump map route after reading your comment. It almost works, but it wipes out the wrinkles bump map UV that I had in place. Sculpting isn't an option unfortunately as I want this to be a mesh which I can drop any new design onto. That works great so far - just not when I'm trying to achieve the holographic foil effect!

Comment: Here's a render of how the bump map worked http://tinyurl.com/oookwja It just didn't achieve the flat black.